# Test whole app with Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am taking first steps in testing in Espresso. I can find a lot of tutorials telling me how to test one, single activity with Espresso. I have never seen any tutorial - how to prepare Espresso test for whole application.

I have whole app with like 10 activities which are having of course different ways to each other.

1. Is there any option to test whole app navigation with Espresso?
2. How to test single Activites which are "inside" the app? Sometimes they need some connection with backend from user which is logged into his account. I have to always log to test account or "mock" data for it?
3. If I am testing one app I have to always change "launcher" activity in Manifest or there is any other option for that?

If it is newbie questions and there is any article which can provide me that information, please share it with me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Once Espresso launches your main activity, then you can basically navigate to any part of the app and you do not have to worry about launching different activities. As long as you can find the elements with which you have to interact with to navigate to different parts of the app and know of the appropriate strategy (by Id, text etc.) to interact with those elements, then you can do your necessary navigation in your app.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you got the answer to your question.

If not, take a look at Android Testing Code Lab.
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-testing

I think it has all the answers to yours questions.
If you to need more help tell us here.